# How to test client side performance testing of single page application with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

JMeter does not support the client side performance testing (verifying the content rendering time / page loading time) out of the box.

In single page applications requests are sent to the server as API calls. I am interested in verifying the client side page loading time for concurrent users with JMeter.

1. What is the best way to test the SPA with JMeter ?
2. Do you recommend [Selenium WebDriver plugin](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-webdriver)?
3. Is there any other tools that can be used to verify the client side
   load testing for concurrent users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does** (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So I doubt whether it makes sense even to consider JMeter for pure frontend operation, most probably you're looking for `Performance` tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or more sophisticated solutions like [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse) or [WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/)

With regards to [WebDriver Sampler plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/), it just provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework so you will be able to launch a real browser per JMeter thread (virtual user) and the rest depends on your implementation, most probably you will want to query [window.performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance) APIs values to get the metrics you're looking for via [executeScript() function](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))